# Change content of a div from based on json values using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load the div based response from ajax, Here i have four divs, based on the click of a div , i want to change the content of a response div, how to achieve this can someone tell me, thanks in advance

Comment: Read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the content of a `div` on a click, and load the content over an ajax request.

```
$('div').click(function(ev) { 
    $.ajax(/*TODO:*/).success(function(r) {
        ev.target.innerHTML = r; // Set the content of the clicked div to the result of the AJAX request
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, my requirement is i have four divs on my html page, if i click on the first div, the data gets loaded to the resultdiv, if i click on the second div, the resultdiv should get replace with some other content  and the same should happen with third and fourth div, assume that i am populating the result div with a slider,paragraph, image with the click on a first div, now if i click on second div, the resultdiv should replace/shuffle its content with paragraph,slider,image. with the click on third and fourth div the resultdiv should contain some other sequence of image,slider,paragraph